# Question about property of factorial of a number

Tags: number-theory

I can easily find out the value of $k=\frac{n!}{m!}$ if the value of m and n is given.recently I have faced problem and that is in the following:

If the value of k is given under the condition $k(1\le k\le 10^9)$ how can I find out the value of n and m.As far I know there will be multiple values of n and m But I need the smallest value of n.
Please someone help me.

Comment: I would do it using Legendre's theorem on the prime-valuation of factorials. Also if $k$ is prime then $\frac{k!}{(k-1)!}$ is the only solution.

Comment: With the upper bound on $k$ the maximum possible value of $n-m$ is only $12$.  But this looks like a programming problem from some web site rather than a math problem, why don't you provide the source?

Answer (score 1):

If $n<m$ it is rational number. and if $ m<n$ then exist t$\in \Bbb{N}$ such that n=m+t and $K = \frac {n!}{m!} =\frac{(m+t)!}{m!} = \frac{(t+m)(t+m-1)...(t+m-t-1)((t+m-t)!)}{m!}$  if $ k=a_0  $we must decomposition $ a_0$ .

Comment: $15=\frac{15!}{14!}$

Comment: @ClémentGuérin  Yes.thanks

Answer (score -1):

The lower bound of $k$ is $1$.So,lowest possible value of $n=m=1.$.

The upper bound is equal to $10^9$.So maximum value is $n=10^9!$ and $m=[(10^9)-1]!.$

Comment: Please consider mentioning why you downvoted a post....